# Can't add "$localStorage"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I develop methode in app.js, but i have this error: Uncaught Error:
 [$injector:strictdi] function($rootScope, $q, $localStorage, $location) is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.6/$injector/strictdi?p0=function(%24rootScope%2C%20%24q%2C%20%24localStorage%2C%20%24location)

```
angular.module('ppollitApp', [ngCookies, ngResource, ngSanitize, 'btford.socket-io', uiRouter,
      uiBootstrap, _Auth, account, admin, navbar, footer, main, constants, socket, util, profile, explore
    ])
      .config(routeConfig)
      .factory('authInterceptor', function($rootScope, $q, $localStorage, $location) {
        return {
          // Add authorization token to headers
          request: function(config) {
            config.headers = config.headers || {};
            if($localStorage.token) {
              config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $localStorage.token;
            }
            return config;
          },

          // Intercept 401s and redirect you to login
          responseError: function(response) {
            if(response.status === 401) {
              $location.path('/login');
              // remove any stale tokens
              delete $localStorage.token;
              return $q.reject(response);
            } else {
              return $q.reject(response);
            }
          }
        };
      })

      .run(function($rootScope, $location, Auth) {
        'ngInject';
        // Redirect to login if route requires auth and you're not logged in

        $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, next) {
          Auth.isLoggedIn(function(loggedIn) {
            if(next.authenticate && !loggedIn) {
              $location.path('/login');
            }
          });
        });
      });

    angular.element(document)
      .ready(() => {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['ppollitApp'], {
          strictDi: true
        });
      });

    var module = angular.module('main', ['ppollitApp', 'ppollitApp.services']);

    module.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/', { templateUrl: '/login/login.html', controller: 'LoginController'});

      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error means exactly what it says, the said function that uses DI is not using explicit annotation and cannot be invoked in strict mode.

[The page that the error links to](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/strictdi) contains all necessary information.

Considering that `ng-annotate` is already in use for DI annotation, it should be:

```
  ...
  .factory('authInterceptor', function($rootScope, $q, $localStorage, $location) {
    'ngInject';
    ...
```

Comment: almost the same problem, now i have this error:  Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $localStorageProvider <- $localStorage <- authInterceptor <- $http <- $templateFactory <- $view <- $state

Comment: No, it's different. The only common thing between these problems is that this is injector error. It likely results from the fact that `ngStorage` module wasn't loaded neither in ppollitApp module nor in any nested module - while it should be loaded.

Comment: but, when add ngStorage, i have this error: Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ppollitApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module {"_invokeQueue":[["$provide","provider",{"0":"$localStorage"}],["$provide","provider",{"0":"$sessionStorage"}]],"_configBlocks":[],"_runBlocks":[],"requires":[],"name":"ngStorage"} due to:
Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'module' is not a function, got Object

Comment: It was likely imported the wrong way. You provided object somewhere where it wasn't expected. The error explains itself and shows the object that gives a problem. You need to supply module `name` as a dependency, not module object.

Answer (score 0):

Change your factory from:

```
angular.factory('authInterceptor', function($rootScope, $q, $localStorage, $location) { /* ... */ }
```

To:

```
authInterceptor.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$q', '$localStorage', '$location'];
angular.factory('authInterceptor', authInterceptor);
function authInterceptor($rootScope, $q, $localStorage, $location) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: the same problem :(